# how can I access other window controls

Tags: c#, wpf

how can I change controls from another window in WPF? I want to edit a textbox in another window. I already tried this:

```
MainWindow mainwindow = new MainWindow();
mainwindow.textBox1.Text = "test";
```

but that does not work. I hope you can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).textBox1.Text ="test";
```